# Using C# , how can I set a content page property when users clicks on a TabStrip (user control) in master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a web page (Orders.aspx) that gets some orders and show them in a Gridview .
The orders list I get from DB is depend on a field named Status.
The page has a master page that contains a Tab user control.

The user control has several tabs and every tab has a different Status.

Therefor, when the user clicks on every tab, I want to pass a value as status to my content page (Orders.aspx) and then select the orders from DB based on status.

How can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In page load of order.cs you can access master page and control of the master page to get its selection. Even public properties of the Master file can be accesssed

```
Tabstrip tabControl = (Tabstrip) Master.FindControl("Tabstrip1")
//tabControl.Status
```

Or

```
Master.TabstripStatus // Tabstripstatus is a public property of the master page.
```